# What is time required for particle, starting from rest, to begin moving under acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Without appealing to quantum mech.,what is the time required for a particle, starting from rest, to begin moving under acceleration.
Example: Ball thrown upward comes to rest before descending. How long is it at rest, and how do you calculate the rest time?

Comment: your statement "it will start to accelerate immediately" isn't quite true. There will be a tiny, finite, but measurable, interval where the velocity of the particle is zero before motion begins again. VERY few phenomena occur truly "instantaneously". A particle released from rest in a gravitational field must have work performed upon it before it begins to move. The duration of the interval during which this work is performed might be microseconds or even nanoseconds, but it is still nonzero. Is this interval whose value I wish to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a frictionless environment, if a force is applied to a body, it will start to accelerate immediately.

The equation $F=m \times a$ can be a little confusing because in reality, the applied force $F$ never goes from $0$ to its final value instantaneously. For example, when I push a table with say $10N$ force, the $10N$ is not applied instantaneously. In reality, as I place my hand on the table and start to push, the force applied slowly increases to its final value.

So if we are told that a force of $10N$ acts on a stationary object of mass $1kg$, the equation $F=m \times a$ would give us an instantaneous acceleration of $10 \frac{m}{s^2}$ but in reality, this $10N$ force would require a finite time to grow (from no force at all [$0N$]) and reach its final value and consequently the acceleration would also increase continuously until it reaches it's final value of $10 \frac{m}{s^2}$

As soon as a body at rest begins to accelerate, it starts moving. The magnitude of displacement depends on the magnitude of the acceleration.

Comment: You can us a vertically upward moving projectile to have a zero-velocity, full-force test case. At it's peak position its velocity is momentarily zero, but its weight is in full effect.